# How to define the name of the data for the ajax.datatable column name? I keep getting the unknow parameter error for ajax.datatable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

JobProg.js

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
   loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Admin/CMJobProg/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "jobnumber", "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "assignfrom",  "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "assignto",  "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "dateassign",  "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "jobaction",  "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "remarks", "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "type", "width": "35%" },
            { "data": "division" ,"width": "35%" }
                
        ]

    })
}
```

CMJobProg.cs

```
namespace LXG.Models
{
    [Table("CMJOBPROG", Schema = "LASIS")]
    public class CMJobProg
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(8)]
        [Display(Name = "Job Number")]
        [Column("JOB_NUMBER")]
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assign From")]
        [MaxLength(22)]
        [Column("ASSIGN_FROM")]
        public string AssignFrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assign To")]
        [MaxLength(22)]
        [Column("ASSIGN_TO")]
        public string AssignTo { get; set; }

        [Column("DATE_ASSIGN")]
        public DateTime DateAssign { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job Action")]
        [Range(0, 999)]
        [Column("JOB_ACTION")]
        public int? JobAction { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remarks")]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Column("REMARKS")]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2)]
        [Column("TYPE")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        [Column("DIVISION")]
        public string Division { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Requested unknown parameter 'jobnumber' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I keep getting this error, how to fix this? I able to get the data remarks, type and division, but i cant get others data. Acutally how to define the name for the data name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, asp.net core returned json will has a special format. Like this : JobNumber to `jobNumber`. To solve this issue. I suggest you could set a JsonPropertyName attribute for each model property.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
[Table("CMJOBPROG", Schema = "LASIS")]
public class CMJobProgress
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    [Display(Name = "Job Number")]
    [Column("JOB_NUMBER")]
    [JsonPropertyName("jobnumber")]
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assign From")]
    [MaxLength(22)]
    [Column("ASSIGN_FROM")]
    [JsonPropertyName("assignfrom")]
    public string AssignFrom { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assign To")]
    [MaxLength(22)]
    [Column("ASSIGN_TO")]
    [JsonPropertyName("assignto")]
    public string AssignTo { get; set; }

    [Column("DATE_ASSIGN")]
    [JsonPropertyName("dateassign")]
    public DateTime DateAssign { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Action")]
    [Range(0, 999)]
    [Column("JOB_ACTION")]
    [JsonPropertyName("jobaction")]
    public string JobAction { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remarks")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Column("REMARKS")]
    [JsonPropertyName("remarks")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    [Column("TYPE")]
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    [Column("DIVISION")]
    [JsonPropertyName("division")]
    public string Division { get; set; }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brando. I got the result by adding JsonPropertyName.

Answer (score 0):

Follow case-sensitive column name in your model/entity class. For example,

```
"data": "jobnumber"
```

to

```
"data": "JobNumber"
```

Add this "AddNewtonsoftJson" in Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Asherguru your comment too.